# How to call an angularjs function dynamically on 'ng-click' event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call a function dynamically as the function name string will come from database.
ie "myNameIsGopal".

Using window"myNameIsGopal", I am able to call a function which is not there in the controller, but I want to call a function inside angular controller dynamically.

Right now, I have defined following function outside the controller, which I am able to call using window"myNameIsGopal"

```
function myNameIsGopal(args){
alert(args);}
```

But I want to call a method like this from inside of the controller.

```
$scope.myNameIsGopal=function(args){
alert(args);
};
```

Below is My html page:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.16"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-enter="hideToolTip(event)" />

    <input type="button" ng-model="gobar" ng-click="dynamicCaller('myNameIsGopal','banana')" value="click me">`enter code here`
  </body>

</html>
```

Below is App.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

function myNameIsGopal(arg){
    alert(arg);
  }
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';


 $scope.dynamicCaller=function(arg1,arg2){
   window[arg1](arg2);
  }

  $scope.myNameIsGopal=function(arg){
    alert(arg);
  }



  $scope.hideToolTip = function(event) {
    alert(event);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close, as function are defined in `$scope` object use it not `window`

```
$scope.dynamicCaller=function(arg1,arg2){
   $scope[arg1](arg2);
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.dynamicCaller = function(arg1, arg2) {
    $scope[arg1](arg2);
  }
  $scope.myNameIsGopal = function(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
  }
  $scope.hideToolTip = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  <input type="button" ng-click="dynamicCaller('hideToolTip', 'mango')" value="click hideToolTip"/>

  <input type="button" ng-click="dynamicCaller('myNameIsGopal','banana')" value="click myNameIsGopal">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot paji.